# Is there a way to send HTTPS GET request to a url with access token witth Java?

Tags: java, https

I am basically trying to send a GET request to an api, that only accepts Https connection with the access token. I tried sending to http and I get “Page has moved 400 error” . Is there a way to achieve such thing? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us the code how you did it and the error response suggesting that either you are hitting wrong API or have sent wrong data to it which is not expected.

Comment: Why would you want to send it to the `http` site and not the `https`?

Comment: I don’t, It just won’t redirect properly for some reason. Wherever I send it I get 400 Bad Request on heroku, but locally it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is OkHttp code generated by PostMan if you want to send a http request with headers

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://localhost:8080/test")
  .method("GET", null)
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXX")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

If you are using Spring, here is RestTemplate code

```java
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Auth","Bear XXXXXX");
HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = template.exchange("http://localhost:8080/test", HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity,String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would this work for https the same?